# Swapping column elements individually (2D Array) C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

I need to swap elements of multidimensional array (2D Array) columns individually so that number closest to that column average is in the end(back) example:

```
1 5 8 
4 8 7 
8 6 2
```

First column average is 4.(3) so ~4, it means that i need for 4 to be in 3rd row

Second column average is 6.(3) so ~6 it means that i need for 6 to be in 3rd row
Third column average is 5.(6) so ~6, it means that i need for 7 to be in 3rd row, cause it is closest number to ~6.

Expected result

```
  1 5 8 
  8 8 2 
  4 6 7
```

And i was thinking for a while how to do that, but unsuccessfully. I manage to calculate average of every column and thats it.

So i need help with swapping of elements in columns

Thanks in advance  (if you need any extra information just ask)

More Examples

```
Input              Input
1 2 3              4 8 9
4 5 6              3 1 7               
7 8 9              7 3 2

Output             Output
1 2 3              7 8 9
7 8 9              3 1 2
4 5 6              4 3 7
```

1st col avg=4           1st col avg=~4

2nd col avg=5           2nd col avg=4

3rd col avg=6           3rd col avg=~7

(Swapping number so that number that is closes to column average is in back, sorting can also do the job because i dont care about position as long as that number which is closest to column average is in back)

Comment: It seems that your description is lacking some use cases examples. Instead of a sort you're just swapping numbers. When you say "I need it to be on the 3rd row", do you mean it will swap places with whatever number is there? It seems your requisites needs a little clarification so that an algorithm can be elaborated.

Comment: *It is extremely hard to interpret what you are trying to represent in your question...*

Comment: @zertyz i used sorting because i dont care about other element position expect that which is closes to average of column, but swapping also can do the work

Comment: @Rusk I need:
Calculate Average of each column (Done)
Swap last column number to number closest of column average (That i need to do but dont know how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the averages (thus, the positions) and you're using C++, you may use std::swap to swap any two elements on an array:

```
std::swap(array[e1], array[e2]);
```

The internal std::swap implementation is something like:

```
template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
  T c(a); a=b; b=c;
}
```

Comment: @Dj_Bear Yes, it just swaps *two template-captured elements*, so swapping *any two elements* shouldn't be a problem...